# Filter integers(numbers) from an mixed array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, observable, rxjs5

I am trying to filter an array ( which has all type of values) to get the integers only. following is the code,

```
let numbers=  [1,2,3,'test',2.33,true];

  let my = Observable.from(numbers).filter( n => Number.isInteger(Number(n)));

  my.subscribe((value) => console.log(value),undefined,() => console.log('completed'));
```

The problem is that my output looks as follows,

```
1, 2 , 3 , true , completed
```

so it is converting the bollean values to a number than returning it thinking it is a number. Do we have a nicer way to filter only numbers from an mixed array ??

Comment: Why do you `Number(n)` it? What is the purpose of `Number(n)` call?

Comment: otherwise the Number.isInteger()  API only expect a number. So there will be a compile time error.

Comment: "compile time error"? ES2015 is not a compiled language. Please be more specific.

Comment: I am using TypeScript 2.2.

Comment: Now update your question with that

Comment: yeah, I updated the question but it should be same with ES6 except TS is giving us nice compile time check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143056/discussion-between-user2225263-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
let result = numbers.filter(v => Number.isInteger(v as number));
```

Comment: Wow, it worked as expected. Would you please explain the diff  between Number(n) and (n as Number) .

Comment: `Number(n)` is a JS function that attempts to convert the passioned in value to a number: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number - `n as Number` is simple Typescript typing.  you could also write `<Number>n` which does the same thing.

Comment: What @ChrisBarr said, but `<number>n`

Comment: @ChrisBarr   TS does not understand casting like <number>n

Comment: @user2225263 what "does not understand" exactly means? Works perfectly fine on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: @ChrisBarr  my bad, I earlier used "Number" but later used "number" and it worked. So got confused between "number" and "Number" type